# Helm vs Batch kubernetes deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am learning kubernetes. 
I have a few simple containers with secrets. Lets say I have two services , I can put them in a deployment, add an ingress and put all of those in a bash script and run

```
kubectl apply -f deployment1
kubectl apply -f deployment2
kubectl apply -f ingress
```

Now let's say I put this in helm. What do I gain here by putting this in a `helm` chart ?

Comment: Helm chart is not only for running in batches, its also for tempting. Kubernetes config file is hard coded, you will not be able to use the same k8s config yaml file for all environments. Helm will help to parameterize it user different values per environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparison to bash / shell based kubectl apply -f for a list of manifests, helm offers:

- atomic role out
- templating (conf injection)
- upgrade and atomic role back
- atomic deletion of all associated ressources

Basically helm offers the ability to create deployment artifacts which are parametrized and full lifecycle management.